# MAXUMSGS setting - restart of QM

Tags: ibm-mq

After changing the MAXUMSGS setting on MQ Queue manager, does restart of MQ manager required?

Answer (score 0):

Its not required to restart the qmgr. The change takes effect immediately.  But take care as it can affect the performance of the queue manager and may lead to transactions log fill up and transactions getting rolled back.